# Не могу перевести код (вероятно JS) в C#

Tags: javascript, c#

Код, который нужно перенести :

```
var moves = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < availSpots.length; i++){
      var move = {};
      move.index = newBoard[availSpots[i]];

      newBoard[availSpots[i]] = player;

      if (player == aiPlayer){
      var result = minimax(newBoard, huPlayer);
      move.score = result.score;
      }
      else{
      var result = minimax(newBoard, aiPlayer);
       move.score = result.score;
     }

     newBoard[availSpots[i]] = move.index;

     moves.push(move);
```

Я не могу перевести это все в C# код из-за кучи всяких var. Например, как можно перевести код

```
var moves = [];
```

, если это массив обьектов со свойствами score( Хотя может быть что-то сказал неправильно, голова уже болит от этих страданий.

Comment: А если бы это был C++, то не могли бы перенести из-за кучи всяких int/char/float? А если бы PHP, то из-за $, так?

Comment: Могу прокомментировать свой минус, если вам любопытно. Вы вообще, если посмотрите на вопросы вида "переведите код с языка1 на язык2" - это всегда от трёх до десяти минусов и закрытый вопрос (вам просто повезло, что ответ дали под последний пятый минус... чаще же не везёт). Потому что практически всегда это люди, которые говорят что они не знают "тот" язык программирования (а некоторые - ещё и "этот"), вопросы "сделайте за меня" _всегда_ минусуют, ибо халявщиков мало кто любит.

Comment: Вот если бы вы показали стремление разобраться, показали бы что вы половину кода сами поняли, как перевести и у вас есть конкретные вопросы - тогда было бы более нейтральное отношение. Условно говоря, федеральный центр готов на каждый вложенный регионом рубль дать два -- но вы хотя бы продемонстрируйте, что сами готовы что-то сделать. Иногда ещё и ответы минусуют, чтобы не было желающих двоечникам/халявщикам помогать, так что вообще говоря вы не только себя под минусы подводили, но потенциально ещё и помогающих вам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По этому куску кода я лично могу сделать только такие комментарии.

```
   //создается динамический массив или вроде того
   //в C# здесь можно использовать var moves = new List<Move>();
   var moves = [];

   //перебираем в цикле массив availSpots
   for (var i = 0; i < availSpots.length; i++){

  //создаем объект
  //в C# здесь можно создать экземпляр var move = new Move();
  var move = {};

  //присвоение "посадочного места на борту" для move
  //в C# было что-то типа move.Index = _newBoard[availSpots[i]];
  move.index = newBoard[availSpots[i]];

  //занимаем "посадочное место на борту" экземпляром игрока
  newBoard[availSpots[i]] = player;

  //если игрок равен или является ботом (префикс ai указывает на это)
  if (player == aiPlayer){
  //вычисляем (вероятно экземпляр какого-то класса) с пом. функции
  //в которую передается массив того кто на борту
  //и игрок-типа-человек, вероятно префикс 'hu' означает human,т.е человек
  var result = minimax(newBoard, huPlayer);
  //в C# было бы move.Score = result.Score;
  //сам score вероятно интовый
  move.score = result.score;
  }
  else{
  //иначе вычисляем результат в сравнении с ботом
  var result = minimax(newBoard, aiPlayer);
   move.score = result.score;
 }

 //динамическая типизация, она такая...:)
 //тут вместо экземпляра игрока присваиваем индекс
 newBoard[availSpots[i]] = move.index;

 //на C# было бы moves.Add(move);
 moves.push(move);
```

Comment: Спасибо, с помощью этого я понял как надо сделать. Не понимаю, почему я набрал столько минусов. Я например не знал как можно заменить `var move = {}` на C#, но оказывается все просто. Другим людям тоже может пригодится.

Comment: Это потому что просьбы о переводах с одного языка на другой здесь не любят. И по понятной причине, кстати... Т.к. нужно пытаться понять реализуемый алгоритм на языке источнике, а потом уже переписывать его на  целевой язык, а не пытаться строку за строкой "переводить".